# Which timezone use cpanel for cron jobs?

Tags: php, linux, cpanel

Which timezone use cpanel for cron jobs ?
Where can I check and change this in php.ini?

It is for PHP script.

EDIT:

More explanation: I am having trouble with debuging cron job because I can never be sure if script will be executed and when. Does somebody have php script which prints all cron jobs with time of execution and line that will be executed in command line.
Problem is that I have set up everything and thinked that everything is fine but scripts started to run in strange time which was not set, when I check timezome in php.ini it is like I want, also scripts are set up in time I want. 10-20 days everything was going well but now scripts started execution in strange time. Does enybody have some tip ?

Comment: Please visit http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It uses your server's time. You can set your server's time and timezone from WHM.

Comment: i know, but which setting in php.ini, and how I can echo this server's time in php.

Comment: If you have specified timezone in php.ini, there should be date.timezone variable in your php.ini. If there is no such variable you can set it using date.timezone = "US/Central" List of time zones can be obtain from official php.net http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Comment: Cron doesnt use timezone set in php.ini Cron takes Server Time. For Shared Hosting you can convert time as per your need.